# can't validate my xml against xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

Please tell me suggestion where to correct...
I tried much, but couldn't validate on http://xmlvalidator.new-studio.org/
my xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<timeofownership>
<user name="Sana Smith">
<location type="Appartment">
  <articles>
    <pid>AA</pid>
    <product>Laptop</product>
    <OwnFor>30 Days 3 Months 4 Years</OwnFor>
  </articles>
</location>
</user>
<user name="Rooney Mara">
<location type="House">
  <articles>
    <pid>DD</pid>
    <product>iPhone</product>
    <OwnFor>10 Days 4 Months 1 Years</OwnFor>
  </articles>
 </location>
 </user>
 <user name="Rooney Mara">
 <location type="House">
  <articles>
    <pid>TT</pid>
    <product>iPad</product>
    <OwnFor>10 Days 4 Months 0 Years</OwnFor>
  </articles>
  </location>
 </user>
 <user name="Sana Smith">
 <location type="House">
  <articles>
    <pid>BB</pid>
    <product>Desktop</product>
    <OwnFor>5 Days 3 Months 3 Years</OwnFor>
  </articles>
</location>
 </user>
 <user name="Peter Parker">
  <location type="House">
  <articles>
    <pid>CC</pid>
    <product>Fridge</product>
    <OwnFor>30 Days 7 Months 0 Years</OwnFor>
  </articles>
  </location>
  </user>
 <user name="Mia Chu">
  <location type="Appartment">
  <articles>
    <pid>ZZ</pid>
    <product>PS3</product>
    <OwnFor>30 Days 2 Months 0 Years</OwnFor>
   </articles>
  </location>
  </user>
  </timeofownership>
```

And the Schema XSD is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="timeofownership" >
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="user" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="location">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="articles">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="pid" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="product" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="OwnFor" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs.string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Please give me soution for this.
thanks in anticipation.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Is this a typo in your `type` attribute: `type="xs.string"` ? (instead of `xs:string`)

Comment: the error is- "Line 1 Column 72 : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'timeofownership'."

Comment: I get a `lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 37; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_usertimeofownership' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often` when validating your schema. As you cannot validate xml with an invalid schema, I have taken the liberty of editing the title to reflect that you need to fix your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition for the `location` and `user` nodes you have forgotten to wrap your elements inside some sort of grouping node.

You cannot do:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="foo">
    ...
  </xs:element>
  <xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:complexType>
```

You have to wrap it, in your case probably with `xs:all`

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:all minOccurs="1">
    <xs:element name="foo">
      ...
    </xs:element>
  </xs:all>
  <xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: still not validate success.. the error show is- "Line 1 Column 72 : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'timeofownership'."

Comment: @MM Sorry, I could not reproduce the error. The [schema, with the suggested modifications](http://pastebin.com/cG7Y4xEJ) works fine on both the website you linked, and in visual studio express. On that note, in the absence of a better editor, you should really grab a copy of it if you are going to work with XML Schema; it would have caught most of these issues.

Comment: @Alan.. Dear alan; I tried this technique on my other files.. but couldn't succeed to make validate success... Please may you help me to correct these 2 pair schema  [Xml_N_schema.xsd](http://pastebin.com/dT0dCV6R) with its xml [Xml_N.xml](http://pastebin.com/4LgPe4up) AND [Xml_1_Schema.xsd](http://pastebin.com/2T0me0hb) with its xml [xml_1.xml](http://pastebin.com/Fyggduxb) . Thanks in advance..

Comment: @MM It seems you are quite new to XML Schemas, so I recommend you have a look at a couple of tutorials. As for your particular problem, I suggest you try looking up the error messages you are given.

Comment: I've already understood many tutorials from last two days, even I've made many succeed schemas, but can't resolve these....I request you to please correct these above 2 schemas..I've  to submit in my college project..